# setState() method does not reflect changes on the screen when new rows are added?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

> ## I want to implement this layout in Flutter

[image: layout image]

> I did the following steps

- I create a stateful widget.
- Added a gridview. count widget to show selected images on the screen.
- Added a widget that contains add the button to the list that will be returned by gridview to ensure that it will be the last item in the list of images.
- when I clicked on the add button I selected an image from the gallery and insert it to the beginning of the list inside a setState method to rerender the widget when the list changes.
- images added to the list successfully but newly added images have not appeared on the screen.

> code

```
     class _AddScreenState extends State<AddScreen>{
        List<Widget> _images = [];
      

      void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
          ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 
        400.0).then((File image) {
          print(image);
            setState(() {
              _images.insert(
                0,
                Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: FileImage(
                      image,
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
            });
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      }

    
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return GridView.count(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      children: _images
                        ..add(
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              _getImage(context,ImageSource.camera);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image:
                                      
                  AssetImage('assets/images/ic_add_pic.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                   }
```

> the expected result
>
> > > when the user clicks the add button, selected images must be added to the beginning and the add button must move to the end each time I added a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `setState((){});` so early from the method.  Simply pick your image, insert into list, then change the state of your view.

```
void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
      ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 
    400.0).then((File image) {
          _images.insert(
            0,
            Container(
                height: 80,
                width: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: FileImage(
                  image,
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ));
      setState((){});
    });
  }
```

Comment: hi Charles Jr, thanks for you response , but your solution not working

Answer (score 0):

> When i try this code its working correctly

```
void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 400.0).then((File image) {

  setState(() {
    _images = [Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: FileImage(
              image,
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      )];
  });

      Navigator.pop(context);
   });
}
```

> but its added only one image , i don't understand why setState method rerender ui with this code but not working with the above when i use insert method

Comment: I think there is clever caching going on in the background, so you need to have a brand new list to invalidate the cache.